# How do I select JSON object and assign it to html dropdown in flask?

Tags: python, jquery, json, flask, jinja2

My flask functions return json like this: I want to select certain object from it and assign it to my html dropdown. For example, how can I select only "Comapany Name" from this JSON and assign it to my html dropdown.

```
[
  {
    "180 Days": "-", 
    "360 Days": "-", 
    "52 Weeks High": "1,000.00", 
    "52 Weeks Low": "255.00", 
    "90 Days": "749.33", 
    "Close": "820", 
    "Company Name": "Aarambha Micro Finance Bittiya Sanstha Limited", 
    "Diff": "7.00", 
    "Diff %": "0.86", 
    "High": "829", 
    "Low": "806"
  }, 
  {
    "180 Days": "334.89", 
    "360 Days": "382.91", 
    "52 Weeks High": "451.00", 
    "52 Weeks Low": "283.00", 
    "90 Days": "338.47", 
    "Close": "349", 
    "Company Name": "Agricultural Development Bank Limited", 
    "Diff": "-1.00", 
    "Diff %": "-0.29", 
    "High": "351", 
    "Low": "348"
  }
]
```

My flask routing code:

```
nepjson = json.loads(cf.to_json(orient='records'))
nepsejson = jsonify(nepjson)
# return nepsejson
return render_template("json.html", nepsejson=nepsejson)
```

My html code. I am using jinja2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select> 
//here i want to add dropdown of those values

  <option value="name">{{ here }}</option>

</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wagle bro, did you fix your issues or answered ?.

Answer (score 0):

**Your JSON must be like this:**
Change **Company Name** to **Company_Name**

```
[
  {
    "....", 
    "Company_Name": "Aarambha Micro Finance Bittiya Sanstha Limited", 
    "....."
  }, 
  {
    ".....", 
    "Company_Name": "Agricultural Development Bank Limited", 
    "....."
  }
]

<select> 
{% for data in nepsejson %}
    <option value="name">{{ data.Company_Name }}</option>
{% endfor %}

</select>
```

**I hope this will work**